# Как поменять пароль доступа к GitLab при работе с Visual Studio Code под Windows?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, gitlab

Изучаю Git, использую Visual Studio Code.

Вошел в свой аккаунт на **GitLab**, нажав на вкладку "Система управления версиями" в Visual Studio Code. При этом были запрошены логин и пароль, после ввода которых я смог работать с удаленным репозитарием.

Пытаюсь клонировать другой репозитарий на GitLab, к которому у меня есть доступ через логин и пароль. В диалоговом окне ввожу https://gitlab.com/myproject/myproject.git, а также *personal access token* и url https://gitlab.com

Повторно запроса логина и пароля к аккаунту GitLab я не получаю, в терминале читаю:

```
> git clone https://gitlab.com/myproject/myproject.git e:\work\myproject --progress
Cloning into 'e:\work\myproject'...
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.com/myproject/myproject.git/' not found
```

Где меняются логин и пароль к GitLab в Visual Studio Code, можно ли его сбросить? Если я не ошибаюсь, проблема с аутентификацией. Прошу помощи и совета, как её решить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Однажды введенные логин и пароль сохраняются в системе и используются в дальнейшем автоматически при обращении к удаленному репозиторию. Удалить или отредактировать их можно здесь:

```
Панель управления -> 
Диспетчер учетных записей -> 
Управление учетными данными Windows
```

Также существует инструмент **Git Credential Manager для Windows**, который обеспечивает безопасное хранение учетных данных Git для Windows, и используется с помощью команды `git credential-manager [<command> [<args>]]`. Подробнее о работе с ним можно [прочитать по ссылке](http://microsoft.github.io/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/Docs/CredentialManager.html).